# C++ portable way to getting the value representation of a u8 string literal

Tags: c++, utf-8, type-conversion, c++14

Let's consider:

```
char const str[] = u8"ñ";
auto const* u8_code_units = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(str); 
// using u8_code_units elements
```

Is that fully portable and C++ standard compliant? Or there's some clause that says that it's undefined behaviour or depends on any unspecified value? I know that `unsigned char` and `char` shall have the same alignment requirements and `reinterpret_cast<T*>(v)` equals in that case to `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(v))`, so, I think it is completly safe and portable to use it but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that fully portable and C++ standard compliant?

Kinda, but not for the reason you think.

See, you have to actually save that file to disk in some format. Which means your compiler has to be able to *read* that same format. And what text formats a compiler supports is implementation-defined.

However, if your compiler supports the format you saved it in, and that format can save Unicode-encoded characters, then your compiler will do the right thing here.

Even the `reinterpret_cast` is fine, because the compiler requires that `char` arrays can be accessed through `unsigned char` arrays, even if the platform's `char` is signed. And the standard explicitly requires that, when reading a UTF-8 formatted `char` array through an `unsigned char`, you will get the bits you expect from the UTF-8 formatting.

Note however:

> I know that unsigned char and char shall have the same alignment requirements and reinterpret_cast(v) equals in that case to static_cast(static_cast(v)),

That would not be enough to protect you. It works because the standard *explicitly* says that it works in this particular case, not because of alignment requirements and such. `char` and `unsigned char` have exceptions to the rules on aliasing to allow this; alignment has nothing to do with it.

Comment: the alignment requirement is needed to ensure the cast from `void*` to `T2` returns the same memory location as `t2` before `static_cast<void*>(t2)`. That is why I remarked it. And thanks for pointing me out the "alias" thing. I googled and I have already found that strict aliasing exception in the standard (3.10§10).

Comment: Related-question: is that the only way to read the underlying bytes?

Comment: @Peregring-lk: You could just read it as `char`s. The standard guarantees that, within the `unsigned char` range 0-255, there is a 1:1 mapping to `char` values. So if you cast the value 0x80 to a `char`, it is guaranteed to compare equal to the `unsigned char` value of 0x80. Of course, if you want to do bit fiddling for UTF-8 operations, you'll need to read them as `unsigned char`s.

Comment: In the range 0-127 you mean? How signed values are represented is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: No, I meant what I said: if you have an `unsigned char` on the range 0-255, it has a 1:1 mapping with a unique `char` value when converting back and forth. So 255 will convert to *some* `char` value, and that value will uniquely convert back to 255. So doing `some_char == (char)0xFF` is well-defined in C++, even if `char` is signed.